# Ubuntu is not found in the dual boot menu in a Windows 10 system

Tags: usb, windows-10

I have an HP laptop running Windows 10.
I've created a bootable Ubuntu USB from the ISO.
I've partitioned & installed Ubuntu onto the HP laptop.
I can access BIOS to change boot order.

but whenever I set BIOS to boot from USB, the Ubuntu options only offer "run as demo' or 'Install Ubuntu'. There's no 'run Ubuntu' option.
If I change BIOS back to OS first, obviously I just boot back into Windows 10.

Question is simply: how do I actually boot Ubuntu now it's installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GRUB bootloader for booting Ubuntu and Windows 10 is already installed on your hard drive, so you don't need to set the BIOS to boot from USB. If you remove the USB drive and set the boot order in the BIOS to boot first from the laptop's hard drive, the computer will boot and show you the GRUB boot menu allowing you to select Ubuntu or Windows 10 using the keyboard, and then the computer will boot the operating system that you have selected.

Comment: Thanks Karel. OK - so it's necesary to go into the BIOS at start-up, every time I want to use Ubuntu & select it? I don't need the USB stick anymore? D

Comment: You only have to change the boot order in the BIOS one time, then Save and exit the BIOS, and whatever changes you made to the BIOS will be persistent after that. When you boot the laptop after that, it will quickly show the laptop's splash screen and then continue straight on to the GRUB boot menu.